# How to Left join on detail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I have model Customer, CustomerQuestion and CustomerAnswer.

`Customer` **has_many** `CustomerQuestion`

`Customer` **has_many** `CustomerAnswer`

`CustomerQuestion` **has_one** `CustomerAnswer`

When I call Customer, I can get the detail CustomerAnswer, but I want to order it by the fields from CustomerQuestion. How I will left join the CustomerQuestion to the CustomerAnswer, for me to order?

my sample code but I don't know what to do next;

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@customer.customer_answers.join("LEFT JOIN customer_questions cq ON cq.id = customer_answers.customer_question_id ").order("ISNULL(cq.order_by), customer_answers.id")
```

Comment: Why do you need LEFT join here? Insn't INNER join sufficient here?

Comment: And you it looks like you already have all required sorting? What's the question then?

Comment: What do you desire to achieve? your question does not make a clear case.

Comment: I got it. Please see below what I desire. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@customer_answers = @customer.customer_answers.includes(:customer_question).order(id: :desc)
```

Or you can just paste code of 2nd line to common each iterator.

Comment: Thanks, I am about to comment that I got it and same code with your 2nd line.